# Angular 2 - Form element value set by JQuery code is not being submitted with other manually entered form data

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have designed an angular 2 app that allows a user to create a new recipe by filling in a html form. If the user manually enters values into the form, then when clicking the submit button all these values are passed to my service code. The problem is that I have a form element that is updated by a JQuery script before the submit button is pressed, but when clicking the submit button and then viewing the content of the submitted form data this form element has no value. I really do not understand why because I can physically see the value in the form on my screen. If I manually enter a value into this form element then the data is correctly submitted in the form data.

Below is my HTML (The element that has its value set by JQuery is the  element id="image_id""):-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form [formGroup]="create_recipe_form" (ngSubmit)="createRecipe()">
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Name
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="name" formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
            <div *ngIf="create_recipe_form.get('name').touched && create_recipe_form.get('name').hasError('required')"
              class="alert alert-danger">Name is required
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            Image
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="selectFile" id="selectFile" type="file" class="form-control btn btn-success" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadImage($event)" value="Upload Image">Upload Image</button>
            <input name="image_id" formControlName="image_id" type="text" class="form-control" id="image_id" />
          </td>
          <td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!create_recipe_form.valid">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Angular 2 component file looks like this:-

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, ElementRef } from 

'@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { CategoryService } from '../category.service';
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';
import { DifficultyService } from '../difficulty.service';
import { IngredientService } from '../ingredient.service';
import { ImageService } from '../image.service';

import { Recipe } from '../recipe';
import { Category } from '../category';
import { Difficulty } from '../difficulty';
import { Ingredient } from '../ingredient';

import $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-recipe',
  templateUrl: './create-recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-recipe.component.css'],
  providers: [RecipeService, ImageService]
})

export class CreateRecipeComponent implements OnInit {

  create_recipe_form: FormGroup;

  @Output() show_read_recipes_event = new EventEmitter();

  imageId: number;

  constructor(
    private _recipeService: RecipeService,
    private _imageService: ImageService,
    formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private elem: ElementRef
  ) { 
    this.create_recipe_form = formBuilder.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required],
      description: ["", Validators.required],
      image_id: ''

    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  createRecipe(): void {
    this._recipeService.createRecipe(this.create_recipe_form.value)
      .subscribe(
        recipe => {
          console.log(recipe);
          this.readRecipes();
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  } 

  readRecipes(): void {
    this.show_read_recipes_event.emit({ title: "Read Recipes" });
  }

  uploadImage(e) {
    let files = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('#selectFile').files;
    let formData = new FormData();
    let file = files[0];

    formData.append('selectFile', file, file.name);

    this._imageService.uploadImage(formData)
      .subscribe(
        image => {
          console.log(image);
          this.addImageIdToHtml(image)

          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  addImageIdToHtml(image){
    this.imageId = image[0];
    $("#image_id").val(this.imageId);
    $("#image_id").text(this.imageId);
  }

}
```

Comment: I would say that Angular and Jquery don’t play well together. They have separate event systems, separate bindings and so on. So when Jquery changes something in the DOM by default Angular does not see it. You might get away with it by forcing Angular to check for changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would be best way to change the element value instead of using JQuery?

Comment: You mean pre-fill the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery manipulates the DOM directly, but in the case of an Angular form, you create and destroy form instances, and modifying the DOM does not necessarily mean changing the form instance values. I suggest you use Angular's own function to manage form value changes. Try change your addImageIdToHtml to the following:

```
addImageIdToHtml(image){
    this.imageId = image[0];
    this.create_recipe_form.patchValue( {
        "image_id" : this.imageId
    } );
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that Daniel. Although, when I add your code I get a red squiggly line under 'image_id : this.imageId'. When I hover over this the following error is displayed - "[ts] Cannot find name 'image_id'.
any"

Comment: Sorry, my bad. patchValue requires an object to be passed in. Also, wrap "image_id" in quotes since it's a key in the form. Updated my answer.